# Pander list indentation different between Quarto and Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, pander

This R code:

```
pander::pander(list("1", "2", 3, c(1, 2)))
```

renders a list that looks like this in an Rmarkdown file:

[image: list rendered in rmarkdown]

and a list that looks like this in a Quarto file:

[image: list rendered in quarto]

How can I prevent the second indentation level in the quarto file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is way using `cat` and `results=asis`:

````
---
format: html
---

```{r results='asis'}
cat(pander::pander(list("1", "2", 3, c(1, 2))))
```
````

[image]

My guess: `pander::pander(list("1", "2", 3, c(1, 2)))` results in this markdown code:

```
  * 1
  * 2
  * _3_
  * _1_ and _2_
```

which when you type this result into a quarto document works like you want. I assume that the `cat` and `asis` forces quarto to render it "correctly". I agree with Ben that it looks like a bug in quarto.

Comment: This is interesting. I can see by using `quarto render --to markdown` how the results come out different. Can you explain *why* these are different? To be honest, the first version looks like a bug or at least an infelicity in Quarto ..

Comment: I added an edit, short answer: I can only guess.